# Tracing is not working on a .NET 2.0 web service

Tags: .net-2.0, trace

I have a web service written with Visual Studio 2005.  My web.config file contains this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

But any call to System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine is ignored.  When I step through my code, those lines are skipped over.

Is there another way I should be turning on tracing?  How can I tell why tracing is turned off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this to my web.config:

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp"
              extension=".cs"
              compilerOptions="/d:TRACE"
              type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="1" />
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

I got that from Microsoft's [Troubleshooting Web Services article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd801133%28BTS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: So, I guess you were using a Web Site Project? I strongly recommend against using Web Site Projects for web services. Upgrade to VS2005 SP1 and use Web Application Projects instead.